# Access data in nested array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml

From a web service I am reading an xml file with the following structure

```
<ArrayOfStoreDetails xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <StoreDetails>
        <ItemId>138253</ItemId>
        <ItemPrice1>9.68</ItemPrice1>
    </StoreDetails>
    <StoreDetails>
        <ItemId>159733</ItemId>
        <ItemPrice1>35.87</ItemPrice1>
    </StoreDetails>
</ArrayOfStoreDetails>
```

I then use the following php code to parse through the data

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);

$products = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

// convert to assoc array
$objJsonDocument = json_encode($products);
$productsarray = json_decode($objJsonDocument, TRUE);

foreach ($productsarray['StoreDetails'] as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br>";
}
```

I would expect the code above to display

```
ItemId => 138253
ItemPrice => 9.68
ItemId => 159733
ItemPrice => 35.87
```

Instead my output is

```
0 => Array
1 => Array
```

I am real beginner in php and cant really figure this out...
Any help please?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just process the XML directly as it's just as easy (and less steps).

Comment: You need to loop through the `$value` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$productsArray['StoreDetails']` is a 2-dimensional array.

`$value` is an associative array with `ItemID` and `ItemPrice1` elements. You need to print those.

```
foreach ($productsarray['StoreDetails'] as $value) {
  echo $value['ItemID'] . " => " . $value['ItemPrice1'] . "<br>";
}
```